# parsing n hex digits using attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

Okay so I need to parse n digits of hex and I am having a problem where I cant stop the standard attoparsec hex parser `hexadecimal`.

My first idea was this:

`nHex n = take n *> hexadecimal` but that doesnt work because it takes off 4 digits then parses the rest of the string xD

next idea which works is this:

```
hex :: (Num a, Eq a) => Int -> Parser a
hex n = fst . head . readHex <$> count n (satisfy isHexDigit)
```

but the problem with that code is in the attoparsec library it warns against returning lists of chars for speed concerns and this hex parser is the base of my whole program

next idea to try for better speed is this:

```
parseFragments :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Int -> Parser a
parseFragments n = do
      fourChars <- B.take n
      let hexDigits = parseOnly hexadecimal fourChars
      case hexDigits of  
              Left err -> fail err
              Right x  -> return x
```

But that feels like a terrible hack using parseOnly.
Is there a fast way that is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

[`Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8.hexadecimal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.1.6/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v:hexadecimal) is [implemented as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.1.1/docs/src/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#hexadecimal):

```
hexadecimal :: (Integral a, Bits a) => Parser a
hexadecimal = B8.foldl' step 0 `fmap` I.takeWhile1 isHexDigit
  where
    isHexDigit w = (w >= 48 && w <= 57) ||
                   (w >= 97 && w <= 102) ||
                   (w >= 65 && w <= 70)
    step a w | w >= 48 && w <= 57  = (a `shiftL` 4) .|. fromIntegral (w - 48)
             | w >= 97             = (a `shiftL` 4) .|. fromIntegral (w - 87)
             | otherwise           = (a `shiftL` 4) .|. fromIntegral (w - 55)
```

You can use pretty much the same, except that you need to insepct the result of `take`, as some of your characters might not be valid hexadecimal characters. You could use `(Maybe a -> Word8 -> Maybe a)` to put both in the same function, but for simplicity, I've used the functions from above:

```
fixedHexadecimal :: (Integral a, Bits a) => Int -> Parser a
fixedHexadecimal n = do
    bytes <- A.take n
    if B8.all isHexDigit bytes 
      then B8.foldl' step 0 bytes
      else fail "fixedHexadecimal"

  where isHexDigit = -- see above
        step       = -- see above
```